# esc before saving or before displaying does it matter?

Tags: metabox, post-meta, escaping

In a lot of how to create a custom meta box tutorials, when saving data, i.e., update_post_meta the data is escaped:

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'city', esc_attr( ucwords( $_POST['city'] ) ) );
```

Some tutorials do not esc when saving and do it on screen output.

However, escaping protects the output to the screen, i.e., echo:

```
echo esc_attr( $city );
```

So does it matter if you esc before you output to the screen or before it's saved?

If you esc on save does the order of esc-ing, sanitizing and validating matter?

Do you esc then sanitize and validate or sanitize, esc and sanitize . . . etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it does. Escaping depends on context and in worst case like using `esc_html` when writing directly to the DB are just a security hole.

Even if there is no security issue, there is theoretical one. The user asked you to store A, and you are storing B. In a simple cases B is exactly how A should be displayed in  the HTML, but life is rarely simple and while at one point you want to display A in an input for which you want to do `esc_attr` and at another in a textarea for which you will want to use `esc_html`. If you already transformed A into B in the DB, it is a PITA to reconstruct for B what was the original A to apply the correct escape function on it.

Rule of thumb: In the DB you should store the raw values the user submitted (probably sanitized, but not escaped), escaping should be done only on output.

Comment: Last sentence summed it up perfectly - "sanitize on insert, escape on output"

Comment: There does seems to be an exception: esc_url_raw which is used to inserting where as esc_url is for the screen. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url_raw

Answer (score 2):

Input from the user or other functions etc you validate and sanitize. For sanitizing sql strings before execution (important one!) look at this page http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation under Database. When you want to sanitize input from a not trusted source then sanitize look under text input or use http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_text_field which is also on the first page under text nodes. Now you can more safely use sql strings crafted dynamically in your scripts and store them safely in a database. The thing about esc_html is only for the browser and to display symbols like & which also can be seen as code and displayed incorrectly, nothing more.

If you want to be sure that you always use the same data then json_encode it UNICODE, convert it to a base64 string and than store it or send it.

Comment: "json_encode it UNICODE, convert it to a base64" great trick! even though it adds a little space it is quite awesome.

Comment: this is the way twitter public streaming api and other larger websites with api's do send strings and objects from api to endpoint so I did not think of it myself. I use it for sure sometimes

Comment: I am surprised!! I was only limited to using `json_encode()`, now totally going for the base64 conversion. Thank you!